# Android - How to develop Custom Launcher for Home Key?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-intent, android-launcher

Since many days Em wondering to find a solution for Android Launcher Application. What we want is to make customized launcher application so we can hide some of the applications from our office devices.

What I did till now?

1. I used the below Code in Manifest.

   ```
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
       </intent-filter>
   ```

But this doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 0):

add this, you must have to declare category as Home

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
```